# Remove tooltip from level 2 of treemap (using highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have made a two level treemap using highcharts. Level 1 shows the default tooltip, which is as per my requirement. I do not want to have any tooltip at level 2. Please help.[Level 1 tooltip: Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vckCp.png) [Level 2 tooltip-not required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUV0j.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a tooltip's formatter callback and check if the point belongs to level 2 - the information is held by *point.node.level*:

```
tooltip: {
     formatter: function (tooltip) {
        return this.point.node.level !== 2
            ? tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip)
            : false;
     }
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r4de9xz7/